# Read particular numbers from a particular line

Tags: python, file-io

I have a certain text file from which stores certain properties about 'n' number of points. The lines of the file are as follows:

```
line 1 yy  
line 2 zz    
line 3 aa    
line 4 bb   
line 5 cc     
line 6  Absolute values 
line 7                    lut                    flp                   err
line 8 POINT 1
line 9     p      1692611.81738281      1692410.66790291      0.00011884
line 10    v            0.03333289            0.03333289      0.00000000
line 11    s         2238.03499519         2238.03499519      0.00000000
line 12    T          320.62832154          320.67108467      0.00013337
line 13 POINT 2
line 14     p      3031521.94006348      3030845.24499738     0.00022322
line 15     v            0.01444968            0.01444968     0.00000000
line 16     s         1977.17270772         1977.17270772     0.00000000
line 17     T          288.46789127          288.45870243     0.00003185
line 18 POINT 3
.
.
.
n points
```

I want to read the number under column err for all n points 'p', 'v', 's' and 'T' in arrays err_p,err_v,err_s, err_t respectively. Is it possible to be done using python? Line numbers have been written just to make it more clear to the reader, they are not actually part of the text file.

Comment: Are the lines in which the values correspond always on the same line numbers?

Comment: @I'L'I Yes, the lines are always fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

f = open('data')

err_dict = {k: [] for k in ['p','v','s','T']}

i = 0
for line in f:
    i += 1
    if i < 8:
        continue

    if line.startswith("POINT "):
        continue

    line_split = line.split()
    err_dict[line_split[0]].append(line_split[3])

err_p = err_dict['p']
err_v = err_dict['v']
err_s = err_dict['s']
err_t = err_dict['t']
```

Comment: Pleas upvote as well if you are happy with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the lines in the file; split each line; pick out the part you are interested in; *save* it if it matches your criteria.

Use a couple of helpers for readability

```
import operator
col_zero = operator.itemgetter(0)
err = operator.itemgetter(3)
```

Use a set to test each line.

```
pvst = set(['p','v','s','T'])

err_p = []
err_v = []
err_s = []
err_T = []
array_map = {'p':err_p, 'v':err_v, 's':err_s, 'T':err_T}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    # iterate
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split()
        # test
        if col_zero(line) in pvst:
            # store
            array_map[col_zero(line)].append(err(line))
```

---

A regex solution requires all the *numbers* to have the format digit-dot-digit.

Construct a sufficient regex pattern; read the whole file at once; find all matches in the data; store the errors.

```
pattern = r'(p|v|s|T)\s*?(\d*?\.[^\s]*)\s*?(\d*?\.[^\s]*)\s*?(\d*?\.[^\s]*)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

for match in regex.finditer(data):
    err_type, lut, flp, err = match.groups()
    array_map[err_type].append(err)
```

---

There could be unexpected results if the structure of those lines differ from the example.